# Waterline populate and where is not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

When you do a `Model.populate('project', {where: {org_id: ['15']}})`

Should return the correct records but it actually returns records that do not match that. I have to assume that this is broken in waterline.

Using postgresql adapter.

My code:

```
if (query.org_id) {
        console.log(criteria);
        console.log(query.org_id);
        org_criteria = module.exports.convert_string_to_array_selector(query.org_id, 'org_id');
        console.log(org_criteria);
        base_query = base_query.populate('project_id', {
          where: {
            org_id: org_criteria
          }
        });
      }
```

I have also tried this syntax: `base_query = base_query.populate('project_id', {org_id: org_criteria});`

My logs:

```
{ where: { state: 'ACTIVE' }, limit: 20, skip: 0 }
17
[ '17' ]
{ where: { state: 'ACTIVE' },
  limit: 20,
  skip: 0,
  joins:
   [ { parent: 'external_resource',
       parentKey: 'project_id',
       child: 'project',
       childKey: 'id',
       select: [Object],
       alias: 'project_id',
       removeParentKey: true,
       model: true,
       collection: false,
       criteria: [Object] } ] }
Found Files: { project_id:
   { id: '7',
     name: 'Nike2 Inc. People',
     description: 'the people',
     created_by: 'user1',
     org_id: '5',
     is_private: true,
     is_user_default_project: false,
     is_org_default: false,
     type: 'PROJECT',
     is_template: false,
     color: 'rgb(223,115,255)',
     state: 'ACTIVE',
     createdAt: '2017-05-18T13:22:21.565Z',
     updatedAt: null },
  note_id: '6',
  id: '3',
  external_id: '070a00c03bcd11e7b0e19deb0847dfce.png',
  version_id: null,
  url: '/apps/intellinote/files/projects/7/070a27d03bcd11e7b0e19deb0847dfce',
  name: 'small.png',
  size: '220',
  creator: 'user1',
  type: 'FILE',
  is_public: true,
  state: 'ACTIVE',
  mime_type: 'image/png',
  internal_type: 'REGULAR',
  is_template: false,
  has_filled_data: false,
  createdAt: '2017-05-18T16:22:23.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-05-18T16:22:23.000Z' }
```

Notice how the query has an org_id of 17 on the project but the found record has an org id of 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working as of today in sails. It only filters the children and not the parent. A custom query is required. This is a LEFT join and will return any matches.